# MySql UPDATE with a cutoff by row number

Tags: mysql

I need to sort a table by a certain ORDER BY () and then update one column so that the new value of this column is EXPR1() if the row is in the first n rows, or EXPR2() otherwise. Currently I am doing it in two update statements. Is it possible to make it more efficient than this (i.e. avoid sorting two times, without introducing another inefficency)?

My current solution:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET c = expr1()
ORDER BY sorter ASC
LIMIT n
```

then (assuming m = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl)  - n)

```
UPDATE tbl
SET c = expr2()
ORDER BY sorter DESC
LIMIT m
```

Comment: what is expr1() and expr2()?

Comment: expr1() is 'some date'. expr2() is if (c = 'that same date' , 0, c)